# Call master page method from content page button

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, master-pages

I have a method on my content page that is called from a link button and this works great.

**Method on content page**

```
protected void myMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

**LinkButton**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="myMethod" CommandArgument="blah">foo</asp:LinkButton>
```

I am going to be repeating this logic on a lot of pages and was hoping to move the method to the master page.

How do I change the LinkButton to reference the method which will be in the master page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to Outsource it to the master page? Does the content page inherit from master page?

Comment: If you need no resources from your Page you could outsource the method to a static class.

Comment: The format is as follows: master > nested master > content page. I would like to put the method in the top most master page and reference from the content page.

Comment: If you say page, do you mean a cshtml or the cs file of the controller?